# MS Excel: How to apply multiple alignments in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, office365

I'm creating a printable sheet using Excel. I'm using the row-column structure to make a very neat and ordered sheet.

I'm trying to set different alignments for different parts of a cell, like so:

```
T1234,              TA1234,               TCA1234,
ST1234,            STA1234,              STCA1234,
```

I know that I can split those into 3 cells, but that screws with the formatting of the rest of the sheet, requiring me to do a lot of unnecessary horizontal merges, which itself lends to complications in formatting.

I know that in MS Word there is an option to set different alignments on different parts of a line. Is there a similar formatting option in Excel?

Comment: There is no way to do this automatically.  It would require you to use a monospace font and either manually or code the correct number of spaces.

Comment: Thanks--that was what I fell upon barring another option. Seems like I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I do believe this is what you are looking for.*

**Earlier:**

[image]

Now apply,,

- **F**ormat cells , **A**lignment,  **T**ext alignment.
- Apply **D**istributed Indent for **H**orizontal and **D**istributed for **V**ertical.

**After:**

[image]

**N.B.**

- *It aligns the first word to the Left, Middle to second, and Right alignment to the last word in the cell.*

Comment: That's amazing, who the heck knew. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you @Yehuda,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score -1):

Using the format in the answer provided... there's an interesting effect if you in-cell format pieces of the text differently. For example, making the third "B" of "BBBB78" red instead of black. Been around quite a long while, but no one talks about it and no one fixes it.

Comment: While this may be an interesting effect of in-cell formatting, this is not actually an answer to OP's question. Your suggestion doesn't attempt to either explain why OP cannot format as he or she wants or how he or she might do so.